# Redis - how to store my data?

Tags: memory-management, redis, node-redis, nosql

In the redis site , in "memory optimization" it says that small hashes use way less memory than a few keys so it is better to store a small hash with few fields instead of a few keys so I thought of making,for example, a users hash and storing the users in fields as json serialized data but how about my hash is REALLY big meaning I have a lot of fields.

Is it better to store the users as a single hash with a lot of fields or as several small hashes ??

Im asking this because in the redis site it says that "small" hashes are better than several keys for storing a couple of values but I dont know if it still aplies for really big hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best solution is creating a key per user, perhaps named by the users `id` and storing the json data.

We tried storing each user as 1 hash per user and then fields for each of the users properties, but we found we never really used the fields individually and in most cases needed most of the data (`HGETALL`), so switched to storing json - which also helps with preserving data types.

Would need more detail as to what and how you're trying to store the data to give more suggestions really.

Comment: Do you mean one hash field with a json as value on a users hash??

Comment: I meant using a standard key via GET/SET

Comment: I agree with this. The other restriction of hashes is you cant maintain nested relationships without converting the nested object to jsons (or other serialized string) to put into hash fields. This is becomes messy and pointless may as well just serialize the whole lot into json and use the string data type.

Comment: I know it is kinda messy but the thing is that storing a typical GET/SET key consumes more resources right? or at least it says something like that in the redis documentation

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a user like this:

```
{"ID": "344", "Name": "Blah", "Occupation": "Engineer", "Telephone": [ "550-33...", ...] }
```

You would serialize the JSON and store it as what Redis says String. I.e. you would use the "GET" and "SET" commands.

e.g.

```
SET "user:344" "<SERIALIZED>
```

Since "users" is one of your main objects, it is not a small hash.

The gist of the documentation is about having hashes will small number of elements. For example, let's say that in your whole system you have 10 colors, and you want to associate some data with each of them. Instead of doing:

```
color:blue -> DATA, color:white -> DATA
```

It is better to you the hash.

```
colors -> blue -> DATA
colors -> while -> DATA
```